# My calculator prints out 1, instead of 1-1-1

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a calculator in Xcode. When I press the one button, it prints out 1. When I press 1, 3 times, I want it to be 111, but it is 1 still.

**CODE:**

```
-(IBAction)one:(id)sender{
    NSString *myLabel = @"0";
    NSString *myNumber = @"1";
    calcLabel.text = myLabel;
    if ([calcLabel.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        myLabel = @"";
    }
    myLabel = [myLabel stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myNumber]];
    NSLog(@"%@", myLabel);
    calcLabel.text = myLabel;
    if (calcLabel.text.length == 8) {
        calcLabel.text = @"TOO LONG";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third line,

```
calcLabel.text = myLabel;
```

is resetting the label every time the one key is pressed.  You're also never using the text that's already in the label, other than to check if it's `@"0"`.

Perhaps remove that third line and change the first line to

```
NSString *myLabel = calcLabel.text;
```

and maybe change the `if` statement to

```
if ([myLabel isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
```

---

Or, alternately:

```
- (IBAction)one:(id)sender {
    [self appendDigit:@"1"];
}

- (void)appendDigit:(NSString *)digit {
    if ([calcLabel.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        calcLabel.text = @"";
    }
    calcLabel.text = [calcLabel.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    NSLog(@"%@", calcLabel.text);
    if (calcLabel.text.length >= 8) {
        calcLabel.text = @"TOO LONG";
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes the output: '2014-05-25 10:37:34.709 Calculator[38621:60b] 1
2014-05-25 10:37:35.020 Calculator[38621:60b] 01
2014-05-25 10:37:35.559 Calculator[38621:60b] 01
2014-05-25 10:37:36.199 Calculator[38621:60b] 01'